# Nested radicals with logarithms

Tags: asymptotics, nested-radicals

The Wikipedia page about [Nested radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Nested_radical) lists the following formula:

$$ \sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\sqrt{n+\cdots}}}} = \tfrac12\left(1 +
\sqrt {1+4n}\right)  = \Theta(\sqrt{n})$$

Suppose we replace the $\sqrt$ operator with the following function:

$$f(n) = \sqrt{n \ln{n}}$$

What is an asymptotic bound on:

$$ f{(n+f{(n+f{(n+f{(n+\cdots)))}}}} $$
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ be the limit, then

$L=f(n+L)=\sqrt{(n+L)\ln (n+L)}$

$L^{2}=(n+L)\ln(n+L)$

By $GM \leq AM$,

$L<\frac{n+L+\ln(n+L)}{2} \implies L<n+\ln(n+L)$

It seems that $L=o(n)$.

Trying to expand the RHS asymptotically, by Mathematica or else:

$L^{2} = n\ln n+L(1+\ln n)+O \left( \frac{L^{2}}{n} \right)$

By quadratic formula,

$L \sim \frac{(1+\ln n)+\sqrt{(1+\ln n)^{2}+4n\ln n}}{2}$

$L= \sqrt{n\ln n}+\frac{\ln n+1}{2}+
   O\left( \ln n \, \sqrt{\frac{\ln n}{n}} \right)$.

Comment: So, is it true that the infinite expression is just $\Theta(f(n))$?

Comment: Most likely to be, cause $f'(n)=\frac{\ln n+1}{2\sqrt{n\ln n}} \to 0$, as $n\to \infty$ and the iterations won't blow up easily.

Comment: You can also write $n=\exp(W(L^2)) -L$ where $W()$ is the Lambert function